# 'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly

Tags: swift

Пожалуйста помогите 
'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly

[image]

Comment: Just do what the error message says. Also do not post images of code.

Comment: сможете помочь ? пожалуйста

Comment: Мы можем помочь, если вопрос на английском языке. (Translation: We can help if the question is in English.)

Comment: Существует также сайт переполнения стека на русском языке. (Translation: There is also a Stack Overflow site in Russian.) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Swift strings are different now. There's no `characters` property anymore. This should do the trick:

```
extension URL {
    func makeStandardizedLastPathComponent() -> String {
        return lastPathComponent.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    }

    func makeStandardizedFirstCharacterOfLastPathComponent() -> Character? {
        return makeStandardizedLastPathComponent().localizedUppercase.first
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/vk0PB3C HELP